# folder and associated files are "missing" but their size still exists

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, filesystems

I turned on my external SSD hard drive today (64GB) to find that an entire folder was missing.  It contained about 23GB of info, and none of it shows up in windows explorer.  Programs trying to access files in that folder say that it doesn't exist.  However, when I right-click on the drive and go to properties, it shows the used space as 23GB.  I've tried using Recuva to look for the missing files, but they don't show up.  What's going on here?  I've been using this drive for a year with no problems.

Comment: Do you have explorer set to view hidden files? Perhaps you hid them by accident.

Comment: are you sure you have ownership of the files? external drives get their permissions mixed up a lot moving between systems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the files and folders are hidden, as was suggested by Jason C.
If you have Windows 7 installed:
To show hidden files and folders, bring up Windows Explorer (any folder will do)
Click Organize, which should be in the top left corner, which will bring up a drop-down menu.
Click "Folder and search options" (without the quotes, of course.)
On the window that just came up, click the view tab.
Then, in the view tab, look under the "Advanced Settings" and click the radio button entitled "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
Finally, click apply.
Then go back to where the folder is missing, and see if it's there, but greyed out. If it is, it is hidden.

If you have Windows XP (as you didn't specify, OP)
Open Folder Options in Control Panel.
Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
Click Appearance and Themes, and then click Folder Options.
On the View tab, under Hidden files and folders, click Show hidden files and folders.
And finally, the same thing applies. go back to where it's missing and check for it.
(Source: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/win_fcab_show_file_extensions.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score -1):

Check for malware using [Malwarebytes Trial Edition](http://www.malwarebytes.org) and then back up your files, including hidden files, from the SSD using another computer.

If this doesn't work, then it may be failing.